# Bin allocation not assigning right amounts

Tags: php, allocation

I have an array that can contain anything from 4 to 4000 entries, I have to evenly assign the amounts across 4 people. I am struggling just to get my code to do as I need.

As you can see my allocation to the arrays are not as desired.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 80 [7] => 40 [8] => 50 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [1] => 80 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [2] => 70 [6] => 30 )
        [3] => Array ( [3] => 60 [5] => 40 )  
      )
```

- array 0 has total of 150
- array 1 has total of 80
- array 2 has total of 100
- array 3 has total of 100

Code:

```
<?php
arrayBuilder();
function arrayBuilder()
{
    $list_of_items = [80, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80];
    rsort($list_of_items);
    $number_of_cont = 4;
    $weight_of_items = array_sum($list_of_items);
    $weight_per_cont = ($weight_of_items/$number_of_cont);
    $containers = [];
    $sumArray = $newArray = [];
    $containersSorted = buildArray($list_of_items,$number_of_cont,$containers,$weight_per_cont);
    $itemsNotAdded = itemsNotINArray($list_of_items, $containersSorted);
    foreach ($containersSorted as $k => $subArray) {
        foreach ($subArray as $id => $value) {
            if(isset($sumArray[$k])) {
                $sumArray[$k] += $value;
            }else{
                $sumArray[$k] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    sort($sumArray);
    $itemsNotAdded = array_values($itemsNotAdded);
    foreach($itemsNotAdded as $key => $value){
        foreach($sumArray as $minkey => $minval){
            if($minkey == $key) {
                $containersSorted[$key][] = $value;
                unset($itemsNotAdded[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($containersSorted);
};

function itemsNotINArray($list_of_items, $containersSorted){
    foreach($containersSorted as $conid => $conval){
        foreach($list_of_items as $key => $value){
            if(key_exists($key,$conval)){
               unset($list_of_items[$key]);
               continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return $list_of_items;
};

  function getMisMatchKey($itemsNotAdded, $containersSorted){

  }

  function buildArray($list_of_items,$number_of_cont,$containers, 
  $weight_per_cont){
    foreach($list_of_items as $key => $item) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_cont; $i++) {
            $total = (isset($containers[$i])) ? array_sum($containers[$i]) : 0;
            if (($total + $item) < $weight_per_cont) {
                $containers[$i][$key] = $item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $containers;

};
?>
```

Should have worked it out evenly

```
Array ( [0] =>  Array ( [0] => 80 [7] => 20 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [1] =>  80 [6] => 30 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [2] => 70 [8] => 40 )  
        [3] => Array ( [3] => 60 [5] => 50 )
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

This splits the array into arrays with pairs of the value 80:

```
public function action_binAllocation()
{
    $list_of_items = [80, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 10, 70];
    $sum = 80;
    $evenlySortedArray = $this->findPairsInArrayWhereSum($sum, $list_of_items);
    print_r($evenlySortedArray);
}

public function findPairsInArrayWhereSum($sum, $arr = [])
{
    $s = [];
    $evenlyDistributedArrays = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $temp = $sum - $arr[$i];
        $s[] = $arr[$i];
        if (in_array($temp, $s)) {
            $evenlyDistributedArray[] = [$arr[$i], $temp];
        }
    }
    return $evenlyDistributedArray;
}
```

Comment: problem wit array chunk is it is not count of entires but values - each array should have same sum not count

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 80 [1] => 80 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 70 [1] => 60 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 40 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 20 ) )

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 80 [1] => 80 [2] => 70 [3] => 60 ) [1] => Array ( [4] => 50 [5] => 40 [6] => 30 [7] => 20 ) )

Comment: array chunk still does not give me the sum of weights per array to be the same or as close as possible

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 80 [7] => 20 [8] => 50 ) [1] => Array ( [1] => 80 ) [2] => Array ( [2] => 70 [6] => 30 ) [3] => Array ( [3] => 60 [5] => 40 ) )

start arrau chunkArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 80 [1] => 80 [2] => 70 [3] => 60 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 40 [2] => 30 [3] => 20 ) )

Comment: I need the sum aof array devided by amount of containers - this gives me an average, then i need the array to be added evenly into nr of containers with sum of array per container to be evenly spread

Comment: example you have 3 bins. 9 bags. here are their weights. 10,2,7,4,12,8,8,15,23 . so now you have to add the bags to the containers so each container has the same weight or as close as possible. some containers will have more bags than the others making up the sum of weight

Comment: @ccisugar Posted with your code for clarity, I made my own little snippet, this should work for you.

Comment: Ok so yours bring back - Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 107.5 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 107.5 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 107.5 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 107.5 ) ).  We have only those array amount to work with so this is incorrect

Comment: @ccisugar But you're saying that you want to split it evenly across 4 people, that is what I'm doing here. If you want to work with more or less arrays, change the `$number_of_cont` value, how you do that is up to you but I think this answers your question.

Comment: you are literly splitting the amount - think of it as sealed bags, you cannot open them to make the ven numbers.  so container 1 wil have a 80 kg bag and a 20 kg bag, container 2 wil have a 80 kg and a 30 kg bag, container 3 wil have the 70 and 3 hkg bag and container 4 will have the 60 and 50 kg bags. they will not all be exacly the same, but as eavenly spread as possible

Comment: @ccisugar Okay, I've edited my answer, this should be of some help atleast :)

Comment: Nope, your one assumes it will always be 80 or can exactly fit into 80. these ammounts fluctuate.

Comment: $weight_per_cont = ($weight_of_items/$number_of_cont); this will determine the bin sizes, then we do not put exact amounts in, but close to